# OrderBy query Php doesn't work after adding LIMIT

Tags: php, limit

I guess my problem is just about a syntax error or SORT BY should come before LIMIT, anyway after adding LIMIT to my query the following statement generates an mysql error.

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM Apartment LIMIT $start, $per_page";// without LIMIT the if statement works while with LIMIT it doesn't.

if ($_GET['SortBy']=="Price" || $_GET['SortBy']=="District" ||) {
$query_pag_data .= "ORDER BY ".$_GET['SortBy']; // It doesn't work if I add LIMIT to my query
}
```

What is the error and how can I make this working with LIMIT and 
ORDER BY wout changing my logic.

Comment: The actual issue here is that you should learn how to debug sql queries. A simple google search, or reading the mysql error would have told you that `ORDER BY` should be placed before `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completed SQL should read like `SELECT, FROM, ORDER BY, LIMIT`. So your PHP should be written like:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM Apartment";

if ($_GET['SortBy']=="Price" || $_GET['SortBy']=="District") {
    $query_pag_data .= " ORDER BY ".$_GET['SortBy'];
}

$query_pag_data .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page"
```

Comment: what's the point in "sanitizing" `$_GET['SortBy']` with `mysqli_real_escape_string`? what kind of "sanitization" does this function do?

Comment: @YourCommonSense `$_GET['SortBy']` is safe to use as it can only be `Price` or `District` to be included in the SQL query. Ie there is no point in running `mysqli_real_escape_string` on that specific variable. `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes characters for use in mysql queries to prevent SQL injection. By that I mean escaping quotes and other characters in strings not logic errors such as `LIMIT 'a'`. Of course, you already knew that :).

Comment: Even if `$_GET['SortBy']` weren't filtered out, using `mysqli_real_escape_string` would be as useless as `trim`. And this function has nothing to do with SQL injections at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense First sentence: agreed. Is that not what I said in my comment ("Ie there is no point in running...")?
Second sentence: Surely if it escapes characters such as `"` preventing input of exactly `abc" OR username = "admin` in a query containing `WHERE username = "$username"` doing things the developer didn't intend (like returning the row for user admin) it can prevent sql injection?

Comment: SQL injection doesn't mean "something that contains a quote".

Comment: `Is that not what I said in my comment?` - no. I'll try to express myself clearer.Imagine there is no `if` statement at all. **adding mysqli_real_escape_string will do no good in such a case either**

Comment: First comment: Agreed
Second comment: I understand what you are saying and yes I completely agree. Escaped quotes won't help at all there.

Comment: I don't understand that remark in your answer then. It is still misleading, as it suggests that mysqli_real_escape_string is a some sort of "universal injection preventer" (as most PHP folks do believe) or it can do any good for the SQL identifier

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36871/discussion-between-pedro-sland-and-your-common-sense)

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
if ($_GET['SortBy']=="Price" || $_GET['SortBy']=="District") {
  $query_order_by= " ORDER BY ".$_GET['SortBy']; 
 }
 $query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM Apartment $query_order_by LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

Comment: Thanks man. It makes sense. I will give it a try right now then give u a feedback

Comment: @YourCommonSense got it sir.